# The strange bug: Sorry, this is a duplicate of

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, exact-duplicates

I have got a bug. 
I have used other web browsers - the same problem, so it seams that it's server side restriction.

Please, could anybody help me. Any tricks or tips are welcome!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try adding context to your question. Give an example sentence or two of where you have found "you bury other things too".

This could give the filter the push it needs to allow you to post your question.

Comment: It works, thanks. It seams that an AI of the site should be re-learned :)

Comment: I'll note that the AI in this case is actually producing the desired result (questions with more context), so perhaps in its own way it's smart enough. :)

Comment: @martha example of the endemic weak "no context, no rationale, gimme teh codez" question problem that is endemic on English; whatever helps us get past that is welcome.

Comment: @Jeff Atwood: Endemic? I guess we all see what we think we're going to see, and reality has little to do with it.

Comment: @martha http://twitter.com/#!/StackExchange/status/101135410427731969 that's from 2 hours ago. See also: http://meta.english.stackexchange.com/questions/1654/against-single-word-requests/1737#1737

Comment: @Martha: 'endemic' means, at least for me, 'Every time I look I see at least one, usually near the top'. It's a reasonable complaint. These kinds of questions -could- be interesting, but the OP puts so little into it that they're crap.